# Intel ax210 wifi doesn't register on AMD Ryzen 7 5825U laptop

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi, amd-ryzen

I've upgraded the rtl8852be m.2 wifi to an intel ax210 chip on my AMD Ryzen 7 5825U laptop running a newly installed ubuntu 22.04 desktop and it's not loading the driver. Here's some output from relevant commands:

```
$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl
$
$ sudo dmesg|grep -i intel
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    4.272758] btintel: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    4.355604] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0041-0041.sfi
[    4.366291] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.366358] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    4.366468] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.6: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.573383] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: bound 0000:03:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[    4.576160] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    4.576163] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[  184.369934] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux

$ lspci -nnk|grep intel   
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 30c9:0065 Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This is on an hp pavilion, more info found [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-pavilion-15-laptop-pc-15-eh2000/2101006253/model/2101006264/more-options?sku=61D22UA&serialnumber=5cd22372dx). I've also tried removing the pnvm file for the [bug found here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212371#c13) to no avail.

Just to test the chip itself, I popped it into another laptop, this time a 7th gen intel core i7, and it worked a treat on ubuntu 22.04. Any ideas? Or does this chip not work with this chipset?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add output of `lspci` to your question. Do you know that laptop vendors have whitelists that don't allow to change wireless devices?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device works on another laptop it means that it is OK. Some laptop vendors block users from changing built-in devices.

It is not related to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

HP hasn't used a vendor blocklist in their consumer laptops for about a decade. I had the same issue and I noticed that in the Realtek card that does work with that Pavilion laptop, it is missing some contacts on the back and all 3 of my Intel cards didn't have those missing contacts. (Intel AC7265, AX201, AX210). It is the same form factor with the same keying. It's not a bios/vendor lockout, for whatever reason the AMD version of the Pavilion doesn't work with those cards. The intel version of that laptop does (which is what I had). The reason why Bluetooth works is that it isn't tied to the PCIE functionality of the slot, only the USB functionality of the m.2 slot.

I will edit this with images of my Intel cards shortly.